# How to make audio files of different lengths start at same time

Tags: python, algorithm, audio

```
y, sr = librosa.load("SoundFiles/JosephGoal.mp3")
y2, sr2 = librosa.load("SoundFiles/JosephSample.mp3")
ipd.Audio("SoundFiles/JosephGoal.mp3", autoplay=True)

y_trimmed, _ = librosa.effects.trim(y) #supposed to delete blank space in front
y_trimmed2, _ = librosa.effects.trim(y2) #supposed to delete blank space in front
print(y_trimmed[:20])
print(y_trimmed2[:20])

print(len(y_trimmed))
print(len(y_trimmed2))


#if they are different lengths I can take off a frame every few frames to make them the same length
if len(y_trimmed) > len(y_trimmed2): # trim y1
    proportion = round(len(y_trimmed2) / len(y_trimmed), 2)        
    keep, delete = int(proportion * 100), int(100 - proportion * 100)
    keep, delete = reduceProportion(keep, delete)
    dividend = keep + delete
    newY = []
    for i in range(len(y_trimmed)):
        if i % dividend < keep:
            newY.append(y_trimmed[i])
    Y1 = newY[:len(y_trimmed2)]
    Y2 = y_trimmed2
    
else: #trim y2
    proportion = round(len(y_trimmed) / len(y_trimmed2), 2)        
    keep, delete = int(proportion * 100), int(100 - proportion * 100)
    keep, delete = reduceProportion(keep, delete)
    dividend = keep + delete
    newY = []
    for i in range(len(y_trimmed2)):
        if i % dividend < keep:
            newY.append(y_trimmed2[i])
    Y1 = newY[:len(y_trimmed)]
    Y2 = y_trimmed
print(len(newY))

blendStrength = 0.5
blend = []
for i in range(len(Y1)): #Loop through each frame, Y1 and Y2 have the same length
    blend.append((Y1[i] + Y2[i]) / 2)

sf.write('result.mp3', blend, sr)
```

Here is a piece of the code of the thing I'm writing. I want to be able to blend two files together to make a new file with the frequencies in the middle of the two original files (look at the last few lines of code). The two sample files are a friend of mine saying the same thing, except saying it one second later in the second file. I thought I saw this function librosa.effects.trim() which would be able to take off the empty noise at the end, however this does not appear to be the case. I see two possible solutions to this, firstly I could make a regression model to see when the first one and the second one match up on a few hundred keyframes and start from there, or second I could make my own trim function by seeing when the sound gets above x decibels. I do not know where to start on either one, or if there is a simpler solution. All help is appreciated.

I've tried to use the trim function in the librosa library, but this did not help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.